# Sending HTML tags in string

Tags: php, html

I've a variable that contain HTML tags as string.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="20">No.</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>Someone</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Say, that variable name is **$html_table**. I want to sent that variable to TCPDF function, that's why I can't encode special characters because it needed for TCPDF to render correctly, my attempt was make a link to same page like this.

```
<a href="./index.php?printpdf=$html_table">Print PDF</a>
```

Then some code act as a handler.

```
if (isset($_GET['printpdf'])) {
    print_page($_GET['printpdf']);
}
```

As you know, it's not working at all. Even the contents from $html_table not show perfectly on address bar, is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT (SOLUTIONS)**

Just using session variables like @Jay Bhatt said.

```
$_SESSION['printpdf'] = $html_table;
```

I point it to same page and have some handler

```
if (isset($_SESSION['printpdf'])) {
    print_pdf($_SESSION['printpdf']);
}
```

**print_pdf()** is function I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `urlencode` and `urldecode` functions. Also there is a limit to the `characters` you can send in `url`, if your `html` is long try `using session variables`. That way you won't have to worry about character encoding.